# How to avoid Conflicts in Sitefinity MVC Widgets (css and jquery)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, widget, sitefinity

I've started developing to sitefinity CMS and I'm having some conflicts when applying styles and Jquery/javascript to Different Widgets.
I want each widget to have its own Style and its Own Jquery and Javascrip functions.

What's happening is that I'm applying in one widget preventDefautls to all its textboxes, and the other widgets' textboxes get affected too.
I'm also applying different css to the widgets and there are conflicts too.

Maybe the good practice is to use the same css to all widgets.
but still when I want to apply something like preventDefaults to all its textboxes, all my widgets get affected.

How can I avoid this?

Im developing ASP.NET MVC Widgets
and this is my widgets structure

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js")"></script>                                       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />                                                     
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />        

<style>
//addicional style
<style>


<script>
//scripts...
</script>


<div> 
Content...
</div>
```

Some advices about good practices, documentation, or code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For the styles, I generally wrap my custom widgets with a specific class, eg "imageGallery", and then in my main css (which I manage with grunt/compass), I make sure to target that class explicitly. This way, I can have global style settings, but then also style specific widgets with tweaks. And the nice thing with grunt/compass, is that you can have a separate physical css file for each widget's styles, but they all get bundled together for publishing.

For js, I typically inherit from the SF types, eg "SimpleScriptView", and then override the GetScriptDescriptors(), GetScriptReferences(), etc methods. This allows the scripts to be bundled with the ashx, and cuts down on risk of duplication, etc. It can be a little more complicated to follow the Sitefinity layout of the javascript classes at first, but you'll be consistent with the framework, so you can even decompile SF to get more examples when needed.